# Rails joins - select users in same age group(compare by non-columns of table)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I have a table like this "bundles"

```
Bundle.joins("inner join users on users.id=bundles.user_id").where("users.first_name = ?", first_name).where("users.last_name = ?", last_name).where("users.age_group = ?", age_group)
```

So, here, we are getting all bundles based on matched users.

Here, firstname, lastname are columns on table 'users'.
But age_group is not column, it is a model method calculated from dob(column).

How to do this ?

```
AGEGROUPS = { 'teen' => 13..18, 'aboveteen' => 19..30, 'above30' => 31..40 }

def age_group #a model method of user.rb
    age = get_age(self.birthdate)
    User::AGEGROUPS.each do |g|
        if age.between?(g[1].first, g[1].last)
            return g[0]
        end
    end
end  
def get_age
  return unless birthdate
  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - birthdate.year - (birthdate.to_date.change(:year => now.year) > now ? 1 : 0)
end
```

Let me know for more information.

Comment: So how do you calculate your `age_group`? You will have to rewrite it in SQL terms.

Comment: @MarekLipka Can you please do that. I donno how to do that. I will update question with age group model method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with this between statement:

```
  Bundle.joins("inner join users on users.id=bundles.user_id").where(
      "users.first_name = ?", first_name).where("users.last_name = ?", last_name)
      .where("users.birthday BETWEEN ? AND ?", begin_birthday(age_group), end_birthday(age_group)
```

and two additional methods to calculate the first and the last year of the corresponding age group.
So that begin_year('teen') = 13 and so on.

```
  def end_birthday(age_group)
    years = AGEGROUPS[agegroup].first
    now = Time.now.utc.to_date 
    Date.new(now.year - years, now.month, now.day)
  end

  def begin_birthday(age_group)
    years = AGEGROUPS[agegroup].last
    now = Time.now.utc.to_date 
    Date.new(now.year - years, now.month, now.day)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, but here, age is calculated value. birthdate is the field. Can you please update answer?

Comment: How do you calculate get_age(birthday)? We need somehow to reverse that function.